# how to write the word "todo" in javadoc without triggering the sonar alert?

Tags: java, sonarqube, javadoc

I am trying to add a javadoc to explain what a class is doing but I am encountering a sonar alert.

> Track uses of "TODO" tags  (squid:S1135)

The thing is the word TODO is not used as a todo message or with @todo.
Here is my javadoc :

```
/** Model which defines data from the oracle view V_THINGS_TODO which contains blabla */
public class ThingsTodo ... {
```

the word TODO is present in the javadoc but as a View name... 
So far I am using this workaround V_THINGS_T0D0 (as 0 1 2..) but It is kinda bad if someone try to search for this in the database.

Is there any magic trick I am not aware of to not trigger this alert with the todo word ?

Next time I will be more cautious about reserved word :-<

Comment: Nothing wrong with having TODO as part of a name. It's not a reserved word. IMHO Sonar is the one being careless here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the mention [`NOSONAR`](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-//NOSONAR) anywhere on the line for which you wish to disable Sonar inspection. Like that:

```
/** Model which defines data from the oracle view V_THINGS_TODO which contains blabla NOSONAR */
public class ThingsTodo ... {
```

Comment: that is definitely what I am looking for! That's great It is not removing other alerts from the same class

Comment: @baybatu I got a pop up alert telling me to wait 5 more minutes Sherlock

Comment: `NOSONAR` needs to be at the end of the line too.

Comment: @DucTran what do you mean? It cannot be after the end of comment `*/` otherwise the code is not valid any more.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat correct, I meant that if we use `//` then `NOSONAR` must be at the end of the line